# Let user create page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on an e-commerce application. Users can log in and create their own custom store. I have a `Shop` model, and `User` has an association with shop model. The `show` action renders the `show` page of shop.

I want to allow Users to create other static pages like `About` and `Contact`.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

These sound like they would be a set of HTML, a title, a shop with which they are associated, and you'd just call it `StaticPage`.

I think that show and edit actions on `StaticPage` would give you the functionality you need to make this work.

Comment: do you mean like this? => create another model called shoppage and create about and contact action. then shop has_one shoppage . And render those pages? Because I have arranged the pages using bootstrap tabs for now. I have already shop show action render the shop page and the shop page has tabs.So there are no pages other than shop show for now I want let them add pages dynamically.